# Problem with OSM Map OpenLayers 5 : the map won't show

Tags: openlayers-5

The OSM map won't show anymore with Openlayers 5 
I tried to added from ol.source.OSM() but a grey map shown.

```
  var map3 = new ol.Map({
      layers:  new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      }) ,
    target: 'map-id3',
    view: new ol.View({
      center:ol.proj.fromLonLat([10.74,34.77]),
      zoom:12
    }) 

  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`layers` must be an array

```
  layers: [ new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
  }) ],
```